# Why does sum() in python pandas concat when there is not a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

If I do a conditional match in my df the .sum() function works perfectly:

```
print(((df_sheet6[df_sheet6.columns[2]].isin(["Strongly agree","Agree"])) & (df_sheet6[df_sheet6.columns[1]] =='Female')).sum(skipna=True))
```

Where if I do a .sum() without any conditional match on my df, it does not. Instead if just prints out a concat like this: MaleFemaleFemale... etc.

```
print((df_sheet6[df_sheet6.columns[1]].sum()))
```

I fixed the problem for what I wanted by count, shown below, but like to learn the reason why.

```
print((df_sheet6[df_sheet6.columns[1]].count()))
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `sum` will add values together (the `+` operator) if you use it on a column of strings it will do string concatenation. `count` tallies the number of non-NaN-like values in a column. They are _very_ different functions.

Comment: Could you please add an example of your dataframe?

Comment: Oh okay. In the first example you create a boolean index of True False values then apply sum to that. True is 1 and False is 0 when doing mathematical operations, so sum works correctly on a boolean series because it effectively counts only the True values since 0 is the additive identity. Whereas your second example is using sum on a string column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your second dataframe column `df.columns[1]` is compose by strings (e.g. 'Male' or 'Female'), so you can't perform a `pd.sum()`, but can do a `pd.count()`, which will basically count the number of rows associated with this column. As for your first example, the conditional argument `pd.isin()` will give you a boolean index of True and False, which as already pointed by Henry Ecker on comments, is interpreted as 1 and 0 values and consequently can be summed.